# Other else if statement not executed

Tags: javascript

Problem: The first conditional statement else if was performed, But the next else if statement was not performed. It should performed if both username and password are empty. What did I missed?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function(e){
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();

        if(username == ""){
            alert("account id required");
        }else if(password == ""){
            alert("password required!");
        }else if((username == "" || username == null) && (password == "" || password == null)){
            alert("All fields of information is required!");
        }else{
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "checklogin.php",
                data: "username="+username+"&password="+password,
                success:function(data){
                    if(data == "success"){
                        window.location.href="main.php";
                    }else if(data == "unsuccess"){
                        alert("Invalid account id/password");
                        $("#username").val('');
                        $("#password").val('');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Once any part of an if/else is true, the rest is skipped.

Comment: order of operations. Put the most specific cases that you want to check before the less specific cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the condition containing both username and password before the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

If, else if, else if, else.. In this hierarchy. `Any one and only one block will execute`.. If your intention is to execute the second else if .. Then make it if...

So your code should be like below.

```
    if((username == "" || username == null) && (password == "" || password == null)){
        alert("All fields of information is required!");
    }
    else{
        if(username == ""){
          alert("account id required");
        }else if(password == ""){
        alert("password required!");
        }
     }
```

Comment: I have tried that. What it does if all is empty it first displays "account id required" and then displays "all fields required". What I need if username and password is empty proceed to "all fields of information required".

Comment: @DumDumDummy Updated my answer as you required.

Answer (score 0):

if it gets inside an if statement it wont try with the next else, so if it performs the first else if, it won't check the next else if.
you need to do something like this

```
    if(!username && !password){
        alert("All fields of information is required!");
    }else if(!username){
        alert("account id required");
    }else if(!password){
        alert("password required!");
    }else{
        here the rest of your code
    }
```